# JMS queue static snapshot

Tags: jms, jboss-eap-7

I need to browse a JMS queue and filter it based on how many message of particular criteria exists.

But the problem is in JBoss EAP, while browsing the queue, if new messages comes it is also considered in browse which make the process to run so long because this application is continuously getting a lot of messages.

Basically need to understand whether I can get static snapshot of the queue so that I can scan through message without considering the new & upcoming messages.

PS: This was working fine in Weblogic server.

Here's the browser code:

```java
Context namingContext = null;

try {
    String userName = System.getProperty("username", DEFAULT_USERNAME);
    String password = System.getProperty("password", DEFAULT_PASSWORD);

    // Set up the namingContext for the JNDI lookup
    final Properties env = new Properties();
    env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY);
    env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, System.getProperty(Context.PROVIDER_URL, PROVIDER_URL));
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, userName);
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);
    namingContext = new InitialContext(env);

    // Perform the JNDI lookups
    String connectionFactoryString = System.getProperty("connection.factory", DEFAULT_CONNECTION_FACTORY);
    ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = (ConnectionFactory) namingContext.lookup(connectionFactoryString);


    try (JMSContext context = connectionFactory.createContext(userName, password)) {
        Queue queue = (Queue) namingContext.lookup("jms/ubsexecute");
        QueueBrowser browser = context.createBrowser(queue);
        Enumeration enumeration = browser.getEnumeration();
        int i =1;
        while (enumeration.hasMoreElements()) {
            Object nextElement = enumeration.nextElement();
            System.out.println("Read a message " + i++);

            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    } catch (NamingException e) {
        log.severe(e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (namingContext != null) {
            try {
                namingContext.close();
            } catch (NamingException e) {
                log.severe(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO: handle exception
}
```

Comment: included the code used for browsing.... assume initial queue count is 20 and when I browse I just want to see these 20 messages and ignore if any new messages are coming to queue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in [the JavaDoc for `javax.jms.QueueBrowser`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/QueueBrowser.html):

> Messages may be arriving and expiring while the scan is done. The JMS API does not require the content of an enumeration to be a static snapshot of queue content. Whether these changes are visible or not depends on the JMS provider.

The content of the enumeration provided by the queue browser from the JMS provider in JBoss EAP is *not* static and there is no way to force it to be.

Since the behavior your looking for is not guaranteed by JMS I recommend you adjust your application so that it doesn't rely upon such behavior.

A couple of alternatives come to mind:

- Set an upper limit on how many messages the browser will inspect.
- Use a provider-specific management call to get the number of messages in the queue before the browser is created and then only browse through that number of messages.

Comment: Thanks for API information, which I also happened to see before posting my question. But it was working in Weblogic without issues. I'll close this as answer if I cant find why the behavior is different between these 2 app serves

Comment: As noted in the JavaDoc, whether or not the content of the enumeration is static depends on how the JMS provider implements it. I think it's safe to say that Weblogic implements static content whereas the JMS provider for JBoss EAP does not. The point is that the behavior isn't guaranteed by the spec so your application shouldn't rely on it otherwise you may have difficulty such as this when porting the application to a different JMS provider.

Comment: I agree with implementation difference in Weblogic vs Jboss for JMS Queue browser